# How do I properly use nested for loop to range over rows in golang?

Tags: loops, for-loop, go

I am trying to iterate over nested loop as below
but the variables declared in first loop like `varOne, varTwo, varThree` do not get to the second loop

Matter of fact nothing works after the line `for rowTwo := range rowsTwo {`

Can anyone please point me to what am doing wrong or how to

```
func StudentScore() {

    var appendedScores []interface{}

    for rowOne := range rowsOne {
        varOne := rowOne.FirstName
        varTwo := rowOne.LastName
        varThree := rowOne.UserName

        req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", fmt.Sprintf("https://example.com/users/%s/score", varThree), nil)
    
        client := &http.Client{}
        resp, _ := client.Do(req)


        type responseData struct {
            FirstName   string `json:"first_name"`
            LastName     string  `json:"last_name"`
            Score       float64 `json:"score"`

        }

        type StudentData struct {
            UserName   string `json:"username_name"`
            Score      float64 `json:"score"`
        }

        var rowsTwo []responseData
        
        respBody, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
        err = json.Unmarshal(respBody, &rowsTwo) 
        fmt.Println("response: ", rowsTwo)
        
//         var appendedScores []interface{}
        studentData := &StudentData{}

        for rowTwo := range rowsTwo {

            fmt.Println("print vars from first loop: ", varOne, varTwo, varThree)
            fmt.Println("api response: ", resp)

            studentData.UserName=string(varThree)
            studentData.Score=float64(rowTwo.Score)

            appendedScores = append(appendedScores, *studentData)
        }

    }
    fmt.Println("student scores: ", appendedScores)

}
```

Pretty much what am trying to do is use the values from the rows in the first range of rows and use to generate new values to use in the second for loop so i can have a final value to print. So the only reason for the 2 nested for loops is because i need values from first for loop

Is there something am missing or a better way to do this?

Comment: You need to include information on `rowsTwo`. What it is. How it's populated with data. Because for all we know `rowsTwo` could be an empty slice/array/map, a closed channel, or an open channel to which no other running goroutine is sending any data. Any of the above can cause the body of the `for rowTwo := range rowsTwo` loop to not be executed, which seems to be the problem you are describing.

Comment: @mkopriva i updated with more details now..thanks

Comment: I'm assuming in your actual code you are properly handling the errors. If you don't then do that first and if that don't help come back with more details. What's the output of `fmt.Println("response: ", rowsTwo)`?

Comment: it is empty `response:  []`

Comment: Well that's an empty slice. There is nothing in it to `range` over. No wonder your second loop isn't executed. This has ZERO to do with variables from the parent's loop block not being accessible in the child's block. You are probably not checking the errors. Don't expect your code to work if you don't handle errors properly.

Comment: yeah but why is it empty...from what i have it should get data from the response of the api call and then have data..why is it not having data? i tested this without the nested loop and i can get data

Comment: is the logic ok at least, i can continue to dig for the issue but wanted to know if my logic is good and things are where they should be

Comment: The logic of NOT handling errors in Go is as unsound as it gets.

Comment: I removed the error handling to reduce lines of code in question...errors are handled in main code...but i can surely do better with the error handling...still a noobie

Comment: everything worked till this line `type responseData struct {` where i declared the structs ...that is where the problem started

Comment: Look, if `respBody` contains valid json that is not empty and that matches the structure of the type of `rowsTwo` then `fmt.Println("response: ", rowsTwo)` will NOT print `response: []`. It's that simple.

Comment: Issue started before `respBody` but `resp` returns the api call response..so from the struct declaration..that is where things went south..nothing worked from that line...so i need to move the structs outside or something? that is where i am trying to see if am wrong with my logic

Comment: Show the contents of `respBody`. Do `fmt.Println(string(respBody))`, what do you get?

Comment: not `respBody`, issue started from line with struct...`resp` did work though..so things stopped working from when i declared the struct..please check `updates` in question

Comment: As long as your Go program compiles it does not matter where you declare the structs. At all! Add the output of `fmt.Println(string(respBody))` to the question.

Comment: just checked `resBody` actually works also...here is what i get `[123 34 111 112 101 110 34 58 34 51 46 53 57 34 44 34 104 105 103 104 34 58 34 51 46 56 53 34 44 34 108 111 119 34 58 34 51 46 52 57 34 44 34 118 111 108 117 109 101 34 58 34 53 55 57 48 52 49 53 46 53 54 34 44 34 108 97 115 116 34 58 34 51 46 55 53 34 44 34 118 111 108 117 109 101 95 51 48 100 97 121 34 58 34 49 50 50 54 48 51 57 48 50 46 57 49 34 125]` for content  of `respBody`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241634/discussion-between-uberrebu-and-mkopriva).

Comment: @mkopriva can you post this => go.dev/play/p/Ph_juql-O8R as answer so i can accept it? thanks a lot again

Comment: @mkopriva is there a way i can make the API calls for all the rows all once or in parallel? It takes like `30 seconds` to complete about `400 rows`, can i run in parallel and all 400 calls run same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
type StudentScore struct {
    UserName string  `json:"user_name"`
    Score    float64 `json:"score"`
}

func GetStudentScore() ([]StudentScore, error) {
    var scores []StudentScore

    for _, row := range rowsOne {
        s := StudentScore{UserName: row.UserName}

        // request score data
        resp, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("https://example.com/users/%s/score", s.UserName))
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()

        // unmarshal score data
        var data struct {
            Score float64 `json:"score"`
        }
        if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&data); err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }

        // set score field on Student instance
        s.Score = data.Score

        // append StudentScore
        scores = append(scores, s)
    }

    return scores, nil
}
```

---

To do it concurrently you could do something like the following:

```golang
type StudentScore struct {
    UserName string  `json:"user_name"`
    Score    float64 `json:"score"`
}

func GetStudentScore() ([]StudentScore, error) {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    var ch = make(chan StudentScore)

    for _, row := range rowsOne {
        wg.Add(1)

        // for each row execute the retrieveStudentScore in a separate goroutine
        go func() {
            if err := retrieveStudentScore(row.UserName, ch); err != nil {
                log.Println("failed to retrieve StudentScore:", err)
            }
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
    
    go func() {
        wg.Wait() // wait until every retrieveStudentScore is finished
        close(ch) // this will cause the range loop below to exit
    }()

    var scores []StudentScore
    for s := range ch {
        // append StudentScore received from channel
        scores = append(scores, s)
    }

    return scores, nil
}
```

```golang
func retrieveStudentScore(userName string, ch chan StudentScore) error {
    // request score data
    resp, err := http.Get(fmt.Sprintf("https://example.com/users/%s/score", userName))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // unmarshal score data
    var data struct {
        Score float64 `json:"score"`
    }
    if err := json.NewDecoder(resp.Body).Decode(&data); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    // send StudentScore to channel
    ch <- StudentScore{UserName: userName, Score: data.Score}
    
    return nil
}
```

Comment: thanks a million times..will implement the concurrency solution and get back to you....really appreciate the help

Comment: @uberrebu Keep in mind that, while in general the concurrent approach should speed up the processing of the scores, if the external API has limited resources or is poorly implemented, then throwing concurrent requests may not help much.

Comment: one quick question, how can i monitor the cronjobs for the goroutines? I am running a goroutine to run the populate the mongodb database inside the `GetStudentScore` function...anyway to monitor those cron jobs? any tools you use or recommend? i do know of gocelery, machinery but not sure if there are ones am not familiar with or simpler to setup/use

Comment: @uberrebu I haven't used gocelery or machinery and I don't even know what they are supposed to be used for. And I don't know what exactly you mean by *"how can i monitor the cronjobs for the goroutines"*. Given my non-existent experience with those technologies I'm probably not the right person to ask and comments are probably not the right place to ask. You should submit a new separate question. With code examples and well defined requirements.

Comment: sounds good..just something similar to celery for python..used to visualize tasks and scheduled tasks like cron jobs...like a monitoring tool for tasks/corn jobs to know when and how long a task took etc

Comment: @uberrebu I see, I understand better now what you're asking but still, I haven't used those two you mentioned or any other similar tool so I'm not able to recommend anything.

Comment: working on implementing the concurrent version now...what if there are multiple fields for data struct ```var data struct { Score float64 `json:"score"`}``` how will this section of code look like? `ch <- StudentScore{UserName: userName, Score: data.Score}`

Comment: `ch <- StudentScore{UserName: userName, Score: data.Score, Field2: data.Field2, Field3: data.Field3, <and so on...>}`

Comment: any way to pass interface instead of like that? for structs with like 20 fields(for example), that will be very long

Comment: The right solution will depend on how you want to use those fields within and with `StudentScore`. You could simply declare all the "20 fields" in `StudentScore`. You could declare a new type for those 20 fields and embed it in `StudentScore`, or just simply add it as a single non-embedded field to `StudentScore`. And, sure, you could use an interface field as well but that is the worst option of all because you'll lose direct access to those 20 fields.

Comment: for now i only need like 5-8 fileds...so doable..will go ahead and test it out in a bit...hanks for pointing out the issues with using interface...btw i noticed many scores where returning zero...so replaced http with `retryablehttp` => https://github.com/hashicorp/go-retryablehttp and that solved it...but time increased from 35 seconds to 50 seconds now...but better to get correct result slower than wrong result faster...now concurrency can help get better speed

Comment: the concurrency solutions worked also...but the external API blocks many of the requests and when i increased retries to like 100, took 10x slower than non-concurrent solution....time for rotating proxies...thanks again for the help